# How do I save a document (Word, Powerpoint, Excel, or other PDF) as a PDF while also removing any macros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an upload feature that allows me to upload files to a file server. I wanted to strip the content of the original file and create a new file without macros for security reasons. For instance, if a PDF file is uploaded, I'd like to extract only the content and rebuild it as a new PDF file. How would I go about doing this in Python?

I was considering using headless libreoffice to convert the file to PDF. But I was curious if this would copy any macros from the original file to the newly rebuilt file?

Answer (score -1):

Well i think you can use the fpdf module in python.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
  
# save FPDF() class into
# a variable pdf
pdf = FPDF()  
  
# Add a page
pdf.add_page()
  
# set style and size of font
# that you want in the pdf
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15)
 
# open the text file in read mode
f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
 
# insert the texts in pdf
for x in f:
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'C')
  
# save the pdf with name .pdf
pdf.output("mygfg.pdf")
```

but i don't know if it will work with word or excel. but with txt files it will work. you have to install this on the command line. Simply type

```
pip install fpdf
```